# how to detect video call is arrive when my Application is totally close or not running?

Tags: ios, sockets, video, xcode5, voip

I am using QuickBlox SDk(Third Party SDK) when my application is running and video call arrive then immediately Delegate method for receiving video call is execute automatically .

when my Apps is in background i used UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier so at that time video call received method call and display local notification because my application in background mode.

But

how can i detect that video call when my application is close or not running ?

Any how i want to ping the user that video call is arrive when application is close.

If its require some socket related or VOIP background related then please please suggest me and help me .